# Использование LXC без chroot

Tags: linux, lxc

Существует ли какой-либо способо использовать LXC для контроля ресурсов, используя группы процессов, без создания контейнеров?

В данный момент работаю над сервисом, который запускает произвольный код внутри песочницы, и для него интересует лишь
возможность контроля ресурсов сервера, безо всякого chroot. Просто необходимо, чтобы эти группы процессов имели доступ
к главной файловой системе.

Говорят, что lxc это легковесная система, но во всех примерах, которые видел, необходим создавать контейнер (т.е. каталог 
с полной ОС) для каждого lxc процесса. И в чём тогда эта легковесность в сравнении с любым другим решением виртуализации.

Итак, существует ли какой-либо способ, чтобы LXC мог быть использован для контроля и управления множественными группами процессов,
без создания отдельных контейнеров для каждой групп и процессов из этих групп?

*Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13484937/1803586* *(Автор: [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318752/jeroen))*

Answer (score 0):

LXC это не монолитная система. Это коллекция возможностей ядра, которые могут быть использованя для изоляции процессов
различными способами, и инструмен пользовательского пространства для использования всех этих возможностей вместе,
с целью создания полноценных контейнеров. Но отдельные возможности всё еще могут быть использованы без LXC.
Кроме того, LXC не требует chroot, и даже когда вы используете chroot, вы можете связать (смонтировать) каталоги из
основной системы в контейнер: совместно использовать эти конкретные деревья каталогов между хостом и контейнером.

Например, cgroups используется LXC для установки лимитов на ресурсы для контейнеров. Но они могут могут быть также
используемы, чтобы установить лимиты на ресурсы для групп процессов без использования LXC вообще. Вы можете
управлять /sys/fd/cgroup/memory и /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct напрямую, чтобы поместить процесс в cgroup которая
ограничивает использование памяти или CPU, которые ей позволено использовать. Или же, если вы используете systemd,
вы можете контролировать лимиты памяти для групп процессов, используя MemoryLimit=200M или с помощью .service файла
для данного сервиса.

Если вы хотите использовать LXC для легковесного управления ресурсами, то вы можете делать это как с chroot так и без оного.
Когда запускается контейнер LXC вы можете выбрать какие ресурсы вы хотите изолировать; т.е. вы можете создать контейнер
только с виртуальной сетью, либо без таковой вообще; или контейнер только с лимитами на память, но совместно использующий
всё остальное из хоста. Единственные вещи, которые будут изолированы это те, что указаны в файле настроек вашего контейнера.
Например, lxc поставляется с несколькими описанными контейнерами, которые только изолируют сеть; они разделяют использование
root раздела и почти всё остальное на хосте. Вот, как запустить контейнер идентичный основной системе, но без сетевого
интерфейса

```
sudo lxc-execute -n foo -f /usr/share/doc/lxc/examples/lxc-no-netns.conf /bin/bash
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы некоторые файлы были доступны хосту, но не другим контейнерам, то у вас есть два пути:
вы можете использовать совместно используемый root каталог и смонтировать поверх файлы, которые будут отличаться
в контейнере или же вы можете использовать chroot, но смонтировать файлы которые хотели бы использовать в контейнере.

Например, вот настройка для контейнера, которые разделяет с хостом всё, за исключением /home; вместо этого он
монтирует /home/я/левый-home поверх /home в контейнере:

```
lxc.mount.entry = /home/me/fake-home /home none rw,bind 0 0
```

Или же, если вы хотите совершенно отличный от основного root, но всё еще разделяющией некоторые каталоги, например
/usr, вы можете смонтировать несколько каталогов в каталог, и использовать это как root файловой системы.

Таким образом у вас имеется уйма вариантов и вы можете использовать один компонент для изоляции, более одного или 
столько сколько в принципе поддерживает LXC, в зависимости от ваших нужд.

*Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485905/1803586* *(Автор: [Brian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69755/brian-campbell))*